# Update google plugin service?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, admob, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to do an update on my simple application. But I am faced with this problem asking for an update plugin. Help me please

[image]

OBS: I insert `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` inside build.Gradle(Module: app)

Comment: update code and build gradle...and update your sdk repository and your can add class path in setting gradle also

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio click "SDK Manage" (third from the end)

[image]

Then look for "SKD Tools" and in the tools list "Google Play Services". Click on install/updated to the latest version.

Add latest version to your Gradle:

```
dependencies {
   ....
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
}
```

If you updated Play Services using SDK Manager and your gradle file still has older version then Android Studio will show you message to change version number to the latest

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have to update your google-play-services dependency from 7.8.0 to minimum of 9.0.0

Comment: In your build.gradle file should be something like this:

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'

change it to 

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'